# Query performance with variables

Tags: sql-server, performance, execution-plan, query-performance

I have this query in SQL Server 2008:

```
declare @nro_credito int
declare @nro_tipo_CtaC int
set @nro_credito = 0
set @nro_tipo_CtaC = 0
declare @pago money


  select @pago = isnull(sum(importe_pago), 0)
    from credito_cuotas_items cci
      join credito_cuotas_pagos ccp on cci.nro_cuota_item = ccp.nro_cuota_item 
      join descuentos_sueldo ds on ccp.numero = ds.numero
        where nro_credito = @nro_credito and nro_tipo_ctac = @nro_tipo_CtaC
```

This is the query plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJulvE_GM  (cost 23)

But this other query has a plan with cost 0.0099

```
 declare @pago money


  select @pago = isnull(sum(importe_pago), 0)
    from credito_cuotas_items cci
      join credito_cuotas_pagos ccp on cci.nro_cuota_item = ccp.nro_cuota_item 
      join descuentos_sueldo ds on ccp.numero = ds.numero
        where nro_credito =0 and nro_tipo_ctac = 0
```

This is the query plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkcAv4OMM

Why so much difference in the cost??

Thanks.